# UML 2.0 diagram object oriented (Basic)

Tags: java, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4ySa.png

**Scenerio 1 - Image**

- In the main method class how would you represent the above code in object orientated program (java) in a UML diagram. This code may have some typos please ignore them the image is just supposed to provide a prompt to help me understand . I made it up for the purpose to help me understand conceptually.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBebW.png

**Scenario 2- Image**
- This is basically the same question as above but this time I am using a standard class and passing parameter through it. The other bits of the code that are related to the code are not in the image,but it isn't required to answer my question and you can generally see what I am doing anyways with the image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried to model this yet?

Comment: Been researching about the UML class diagram for a bit now. But can't find anything that tell me what to do in the scenarios above.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the code in Scenario 1 being a generally bad way to approach OOP, you generally want to model a class as such:

[image]

Here, the class is defined in the top portion of the model, while directly below it are the instance variables. Notice the + sign? That means this variable is public and can be accessed by other classes. A - sign would indicate it is private, which is good practice.

In the third section of the model are the methods which can also be private or public, depending on what you want to hide from other classes.

I hope this is a decent start for you.

**Ignore the Lion inheriting from Animal.**

Comment: Yeah I already knows those things. Those are the either aspects. I was wondering if say in your main class you have created an object

Comment: say for example  you created an object in the main method class                      Car nissan = new Car(Body);  <- How would you show what inside the parenthesis in a class diagram - "Body" is an instance not a primitive type or string or return type.

Comment: It is badly designed from the start. You are instantiating a car part from a car and not even polymorphing it.

I suggest brushing up on how OOP really works before trying to model this.